# Getting the val for all check boxed with a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get all checkboxes with the class 'testclass' to check if they are checked, if so, add their value to theString.

```
   $('.testclass').each(function () {

        if (this.checked) {   

            var x = this.val();

            theString += x + ";";

         }

   });
```

It seems to be getting stuck at the part where it gets the val?

Comment: try this: Take a look at the css :checked selector, like '.testclass:checked', then do .each on that.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Problem**

The problem with your code is `this` is a DOM element and not a jQuery object. You would need to change

```
var x = this.val();
```

to

```
var x = this.value;
//or
var x = $(this).value; //slower
```

---

**Better solution**

You can use `:checked` in your selector to get the checkboxes that are selected. You can than use `map()` to get the values.

```
var values = $(".testclass:checked")  //get the checked checkboxes
    .map(function () {                //Map loops through each element in the jQuery object produces a new jQuery object containing the return values. 
        return this.value;
    })
    .get()                            //gets the newly created array
    .join(",");                       //joins the array with commas as a seperator
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:checked` with class `.testclass` to get the checked elements with specific class:

```
$('.testclass:checked').each(function() {
   console.log(this.value)
});
```

just seen the code and it seems that your problem is this:

```
this.val();
```

try changing either to this:

```
this.value
```

or

```
$(this).val(); //<---------jQuery version
```

Answer (score 0):

using [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

try this

```
var theString=$('.testclass:checked').map(function(n){
     return this.value;
}).get().join(',');  //get the checked value and join it with ,
alert(theString);
```

theString will have all the checked values commaseperated...

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for get all checked checkbox value

```
 $('.testclass:checked').each(function () {

            var x = this.val();

            theString += x + ";";

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var values = $('.testclass:checked').map(function(idx, el) {
    return $(el).val()
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using jQuery :

```
 checkedList = [].slice.call (document.querySelectorAll ('.testclass:checked'))
                       .map (function (el) { return el.value; })
                       .join (';');
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/AeXWs/

Comment: And you have to hope the browser supports, querySelector and map. ;)

Comment: Agreed, but all popular current browsers do. See http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector

Comment: Map fails with [IE8](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.map) unless you use a polyfill. EOL is soon! WOHOOO

Answer (score -1):

try

```
  $('.testclass:checked').each(function() {
      alert(($(this).value)) 
  });
```

Comment: Because this will alert undefined and it does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
 var theString = "":

 $('.testclass').each(function () {

        if ($(this).checked) {   

            theString += $(this).val()+";";

         }    

   });
```

UPDATE: My bad, missed the part of question, where you needed values too.

Comment: @epascarello read closely: we are talking about CHECKBOXES. Reading their values is useless. You need their states.

Comment: Which .checked will tell you if it is checked, you can still read their values and gather the ones that are checked like the OP wanted. You change the OP's requirement!

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/54/

```
$('.check').on("click",function(){
    $.each($('.testclass'), function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
          alert($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Because it is poor practice using $(this) over and over, and does not build the string.